# Use of Boost Bimap in C++

Tags: c++, boost, complexity-theory, bimap

C++ Boost has Bimap container that is a bidirectional map:
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/bimap/doc/html/index.html

Does anyone know the performance of Boost::bimap? I mean what's the time complexity of accessing an element in the map? Is it as quick as unordered_map access (which is O(1))?

Thanks!

Comment: It depends on the collection type you're accessing through.  Without the type definition it's impossible to say.  In general I believe that the individual collection types have the same runtime complexities as their "standalone implementation" counterparts.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

AFAIK each different container of this library  have different operation complexity relative to the implementation (like for the stl containers). For details necessary to make your choice, read : http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/bimap/doc/html/boost_bimap/the_tutorial/controlling_collection_types.html